# Area of what region equals half of total?

Tags: integration

Say I have an integral $\int_0^{10}f(x)dx$ whose value is known. Say that I want to find $a$ such that $\int_0^af(x)dx=\frac12\int_0^{10}f(x)dx$. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for a general method or is this a specific problem. Is the function $f$ given to you, for example?

Comment: Without knowing $f(x)$, i seems difficult to answer. In any manner, this reduces to solving one equation in $a$. May be, you could add one function of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $F'(x)=f(x)$

then we can get $\int_0^{10}f(x)dx=F(10)-F(0)$

then this equation equals to $F(a)-F(0)=\dfrac{F(10)-F(0)}{2}$

so $a=F^{(-1)}(\dfrac{F(10)+F(0)}{2})$